# Como retornar um objeto dentro de outro objeto usando Java, Sprint Boot e Hibernate numa API?

Tags: java, api, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Preciso criar uma API exatamente como essa da foto:

Preciso que os valores true ou false dentro de caracteristicas possam ser passados via método post (seria legal uma obrigatoriedade de todos os campos dentro de caracteristicas possuirem ou true ou false). E quando der um get, preciso retornar exatamente assim para consumir no front. Como isso deveria ser feito?

[image: caracteristicas]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Ja que voce quer usar Hibernate e Spring, voce pode criar a Classe Caracteristicas e mapeala com as annotations.

```
@Entity
public class caracteristicas (){

   #Atributos do tipos boolean,os que voce quer que sejam obrigatorios e nao nulos, voce anota assim:

   @Colum(name="wifi",nullable = false);
   private boolean wifi
}
```

[Veja aqui um artigo que ensina como mapear classes.](https://www.devmedia.com.br/hibernate-mapping-mapeando-relacionamentos-entre-entidades/29445)

Esse link tambem fala como voce pode usar o get e montar o objeto, utilizando o reflection que o proprio java faz nas suas classes que sao anotadas como @Controller. Sugiro dar uma estudada mais no padrao Rest com Java e Hibernate

[Veja aqui um CRUD com Java e hibernate usando REST](https://www.oracle.com/br/technical-resources/articles/dsl/crud-rest-sb2-hibernate.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou muito!